# How to recreate auth.users table in supabase

Tags: postgresql, prisma, supabase

Is there a way to recreate the default `auth.users` table after having deleted it? I deleted it due to my poor skills at migration. I can't sign up at all now and I assume this is because the auth.users table has gone. Thank you!

Comment: If it's an empty project still, it will be easy to just delete the Supabase project and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the selected providers in 'authentication' section and save, and then re enable again those providers (and save), auth folder tables should recreate again